# Entity Framework - Linq to query where value in a list

Tags: c#, frameworks, entity

I'm using Entity Framework on .NET 3.5 and I can't for the life of me figure out how to write some Linq to traverse the following design:

Basically I am trying to figure out if a user has permission (EntityAction) for a specific EntityType.  Now Users and Roles are maintained in Active Directory - but the system can do a lookup to find which Role/Groups a user belongs.

Let's assume I have the following data:

**EntityType**

EntityTypeId:  1

Name:  Entity One

**User**

UserId:  1

AccountName:  Andez

**Role**

RoleId:  1

AccountName:  MyRole

**EntityAction**

EntityActionId:  1

Name:  Just do something

**RoleEntityActionAssociation**

(association between Role and EntityAction)

EntityActionId:  1

RoleId:  1

I am storing group names for the user (from Active Directory) in a List:

```
List<string> groupNames = new List<string>();
```

**Question**

However I am trying to piece together some Linq to find out whether a User (or one of the Roles he is assigned in List groupNames) is associated with a particular EntityAction given an EntityType.

```
// get reference to the user
User user = context.Users.Where(x => x.AccountName == "Andez").FirstOrDefault();

// get reference to the entity type we want to query
EntityType et = context.EntityTypes.Where(x => x.Name == "Entity One").FirstOrDefault();

// get list of all entity actions for the user
var result = from ea in et.EntityActions
             where ea.EntityActionId == 1 && (ea.Users.Contains(user) || ea.Roles.Count(r => groupNames.Contains(r.AccountName)) > 0)
             select ea;
```

Of course my query does not work above - it does not return any results (result.ToList().Count == 0)

I need pointers on this please.

Thanks

[image: EF Design]

Comment: Avoid using FirstOrDefault when you expect one and only one result and an error will ensue if it is not found, use .Single()

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you need to check User by Id, replace `ea.Users.Contains(user)` to `ea.Users.Any(us => us.UserId == user.UserId)`:

```
var result = from ea in et.EntityActions
                     where ea.EntityActionId == 1 && ea.Users.Any(us => us.UserId == user.UserId)
                     select ea;
```

**UPDATE 0**

Try this code, it should work:

```
var result = from ea in et.EntityActions
                     where ea.EntityActionId == 1 &&
                         (ea.Users.Any(us => us.UserId == user.UserId) || ea.Any(r => groupNames.Contains(r.AccountName)))
                     select ea;
```

Comment: Just tried that.  My initial code did work to get the user's EntityActions - I'd just missed some configuration in database doh!  But I still cannot figure out the Roles part

Comment: Thanks for that...  I am suspecting it is down to my objects not being loaded.  Given that I am using .NET 3.5, there is no lazy loading.  I broke the query down into different lines of code until I forcefully loaded the Roles for the EntityAction that I know it should use by calling Load.  Thing is, I don't know how to ensure that the objects I need will be loaded for queries.  where ea.EntityActionId == 1 && ((ea.Users.Any(us => us.UserId == user.UserId) || ea.Roles.Any(r => groupNames.Contains(r.AccountName)))) does work.  Any thoughts to load nicely?

Comment: Read this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/vstudio/bb896272(v=vs.90).aspx).

Comment: OK thanks for that Linq! ;-)  I've now got my queries being loaded and have just purchased LinqPad http://www.linqpad.net/ to help me.

Comment: PS I still cannot get the groupNames.Contains working.  Perhaps as I am .NET 3.5 SP1 which is EF v1.  I get LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Contains(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `Contains` method is NOT part of the EF 3.0 and was not added until Entity Framework 4.0, but you can use this extension method: [BuildContainsExpression](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/095745fe-dcf0-4142-b684-b7e4a1ab59f0/).